# has_many association rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, has-many

I have a User model and a Job_Category model, the Job_Category model

```
belongs_to :user
```

The User model

```
has_many :job_categories, :dependent => :destroy
```

I have a Dashboard Controller and am trying to display all the Job_Categories for a specific logged in User.

```
class DashboardController < ApplicationController
before_filter :authenticate_user!


def index
 @user = User.find(params[:id])
 @job_categories = @user.job_categories


 #@job_categories = JobCategory.all

 #respond_to do |format|
#   format.html # index.html.erb
#   format.xml  { render :xml => @job_categories }
# end

end
```

However, when I am trying to display this I get the error 'Couldn't find User without an ID' .   I see this in the log:

Processing by DashboardController#index as HTML
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."id" = 2) LIMIT 1
Completed   in 22ms

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find User without an ID):
  app/controllers/dashboard_controller.rb:9:in `index'

Comment: Can you try it int the rails console, is there a record with id = 2?

Comment: I do see user.id = 2 in the database.  I tried it in the console and I get a different error.  >> user = user.find(params[:id])
NameError: undefined local variable or method `params' for main:Object
 from (irb):5
 from :0

Comment: The only thing I can think of, does it need to be in the Users controller instead of the Dashboard controller?  It should work in the Dashboard controller right?

Comment: Can you post your routes file?  Seems like you don't pass the id parameter to the action => `params[:id]` is `nil` => you got an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you cannot try to find by params in console, because there ain't such thing.

Try this in console:

> User.find(2)

(..default column where find method looks the value is primary key which I assume is id as usual)

Then another thing, if you're already authenticating user in before_filter, you might already have @current_user or something set, are you using some authentication plugin like devise or something? So there's no need to pass current users id to dashboard controller. Application controller already knows who this user is and your dashboard controller is a subclass of it.

And ensure your job_category table has user_id column too.

Comment: You're exactly right yoka.  I am using Devise, so I already had the id set, I needed to use:      @job_categories = current_user.job_categories  and it works!!  Thanks a bunch!